# Magento API V2 catalogProductList Filter by category_ids

Tags: api, magento, soap

I'm trying to get a list of `"enabled"` products through Magento SOAP API V2. But I can't get it by `category_ids` via `filter`. Please help me. I'm using `android` and `ksoap` lib.